# Uploading Image in a folder and change name before uploading PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to upload image along with form data. i am saving all the information into database and image into a folder.

My Form:

```
  <form method="post" action="insert_product_page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="insert_product"> 
  <table width="80%" border="1">
  <tr>
  <th width="49%" align="left" scope="col">Product Title</th>
 <th width="51%" align="left" scope="col"><input name="product_title" type="text" required id="product_title" ></th>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td align="left">Product Category</td>
  <td align="left"><select name="product_cat" required>
    <option>Select A Category</option>
  <option>Category A</option>
  <option>Category B</option>
  <option>Category C</option>

</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left">Product Brand</td>
<td align="left"><select name="product_brand" required>
  <option>Select A Brand</option>
  <option>Brand A</option>
  <option>Brand B</option>
  <option>Brand C</option>
  <option>Brand D</option>

   </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">Product Image</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="product_image" type="file" ></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td align="left">Product Description</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="product_price" type="text" required id="product_price" ></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td align="left">Product Keyword</td>
   <td align="left"><input name="product_keyword" type="text" required id="product_keyword" ></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert New Product"></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
    </form>
```

insert_product_page.php:

```
    <?php
        include 'includes/dbConnect.php';

        $product_cat= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_cat']);
        $product_brand= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_brand']);
        $product_title= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_title']);
        $product_price= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
        $product_desc= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_desc']);
        $product_keyword= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_keyword']);


            $sql = "INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_keywords) VALUES (NULL,'$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_title', '$product_price', '$product_desc', '$product_keyword')";

            $id = mysqli_insert_id();
            // Place image in the folder 
            $newname = "$id.jpg";
            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], "images/$newname");


            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
            }

            $con->close();
    ?>
```

dbConnect.php:

```
            <?php
        error_reporting(E_ERROR);

        $servername = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $database = 'ecommerce';

        // Create connection
        $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$database);

        // Check connection
        if (!$con) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        //echo "Connected successfully";
        ?>
```

The data is successfully saving into the database and image is being upload to the folder but image has no name and replace the last uploaded image. I am trying to upload the image having same name the auto_incremented id saved in the database. Kindly guide me where i am doing mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting the full path to the location where you want it to store the uploaded file, in the second argument to move_uploaded_file.

Comment: Has anyone ever told you that you can't mix MySQL APIs before? If nobody has, then I'm the first one then ;-)

Comment: *I'm not a fan of mixed drinks Ralph* @Fred-ii-

Comment: *Those guys so far, are probably already too drunk to have noticed Sam* @JayBlanchard - *hic!*

Comment: *"i am saving all the information into database"* - You mean, you "want" to save all that, but it's just not working out, *isn't it?*. So, besides the interrogation points in my comment; what's the question/problem? Give us a call when you've gotten back from *who know where*.

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies on when you are actually runnig the query.

try this instead please:

```
<?php
        include 'includes/dbConnect.php';

        $product_cat= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_cat']);
        $product_brand= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_brand']);
        $product_title= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_title']);
        $product_price= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
        $product_desc= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_desc']);
        $product_keyword= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_keyword']);


            $sql = "INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_keywords) VALUES (NULL,'$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_title', '$product_price', '$product_desc', '$product_keyword')";

            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                 //you only get the last id AFTER the query runs!
                 $id = mysqli_insert_id();
                 // Place image in the folder 
                 $newname = $id.".jpg";
                 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], "images/$newname");
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
            }

            $con->close();
    ?>
```

your mistake is like asking the server what has created before really creating it :) hope you understand my point and it'll work properly

cheers

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions. That won't work.

Comment: *What a great drink that'd make, eh Sam?* @JayBlanchard I'll have what he's having.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your code, you are not executing your statment before getting the id.

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_cat, product_brand, product_title, product_price, product_desc, product_keywords) VALUES (NULL,'$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_title', '$product_price', '$product_desc', '$product_keyword')";     
            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                echo "New record created successfully";      
                $id = mysqli_insert_id();
                // Place image in the folder 
                $newname = "$id.jpg";
                move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], "images/$newname");
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
            }

            $con->close();
```

Comment: the problem is that image is uploaded without any name, and when image is uploaded it replaces last image. Kindly check and tell em where is mistake. Thanks